# SET with case when SQL

Tags: sql, sql-update

I'm trying to update the `status` column of this table and I used the following:

```
UPDATE table_a
  SET status = CASE 
    WHEN test_group LIKE 'Control' THEN 0
    WHEN test_group NOT LIKE 'Control' THEN 1
END;
```

But it doesn't appear to have worked, it actually just gave every observation a 1 for `status`. I just want the observations that have the word "control" in them to take a 0 for `status` and observations that don't have the word "control" in them to take a 1. The default was not a 0 or 1 for this column.

Comment: Please specify which DBMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the second condition.  But you do need wildcards for the `LIKE`.  I would suggest:

```
UPDATE table_a
  SET status = (CASE WHEN test_group LIKE '%Control%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END);
```

In many databases, you can simplify this to:

```
UPDATE table_a
  SET status = (test_group NOT LIKE '%Control%');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table_a
  SET status = CASE 
    WHEN test_group LIKE '%Control%' THEN 0
    WHEN test_group NOT LIKE '%Control%' THEN 1
END;
```

Comment: Please use these tips to format your code: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (T-SQL):

```
UPDATE table_a
  SET status = CASE 
    WHEN charindex('Control', test_group)>0 THEN 0
    ELSE 1
END;
```